# Underscripted Equals Symbol

Tags: subscripts

Is there a non-crazy way I can implement a simple = sign with a condition/scope written under it?
In particular, `(expr1) = (x->a) (expr2)`, where `(x->a)` is written like in a limit, under the equals sign?

Comment: @moewe This messes with the spacing of the `=` sign.  It should be `\mathrel{\underset{x \to a}{=}}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I thought as much, but didn't test it thoroughly - in the one case I tested it it seemed fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\underrel[2]{\mathrel{\mathop{#2}\limits_{#1}}}
\begin{document}
$x \underrel{x\to a}{=} a$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

You could also add an optional argument which enables you to let the underset content bleed to the left and right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\underrel[3][]{\mathrel{\mathop{#3}\limits_{%
      \ifx c#1\relax\mathclap{#2}\else#2\fi}}}
\begin{document}
$
x \underrel{x\to a}{=} a
\quad
x \underrel[c]{x\to a}{=} a
$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: `\underset{x\to a}{=}` is easier (requires `amsmath`); it makes the composed symbol an atom of the same nature as the second argument (a relation, in this case), if it's a single symbol.